# Navigation Drawer "Up" button when in deeper sections

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to transform the upper left button that normally allows to open the Navigation Drawer to become a "Up" button (with the left arrow).
I looked everywhere but I couldn't find even a question where this problem is answered in a quick way.

Details:
I have a single Activity. The NavigationDrawer contains a list of elements. Let's call them Element1 and so on.
When I open the application I can see a "Home" Fragment that contains a sort of splash screen with some basic details of my application.
If I open the Drawer and select Element4 I switch the "Home" Fragment with the "Element4" Fragment. The icon at the top left should become the classic "Up" icon as intended in the Google developer site and allow me, touching it, to come back to the "Home" Fragment.

A simple example could be the NavigationDrawer application mockup created by Eclipse in its wizard. I want to modify it to make the 0 section the home section and if the 1 section its child.

Maybe if someone that knows how to do answer me it'll be a big help not only for me but for many other people.
Thanks

Comment: Can you be please more specific, what do you want to do, do you want to make another position for navigation drawer or you want to change the button logo.?